# Rails, Highchart maps - adding custom data

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, highcharts, highmaps

I need some basic assistance with a Highmap (via Highcharts) I am trying to put in my Rails 4 app. I suspect I have some fundamental misunderstanding of it but can't find any clear guidance.

See a simple fiddle taken from the documentation, here

http://jsfiddle.net/SimonWalsh/zpdc1btu/

What I ultimately need to do is provide membership numbers for each country so that it will be displayed much the same as the population density is in this map.

I know I need to provide my data and the means to join it to the map data in

```
 series : [{
      data : data,
      mapData: Highcharts.maps['custom/world'],
      joinBy: ['iso-a2', 'code'],
      name: 'Population density',
      states: {
           hover: {
                color: '#BADA55'
           }
      }
 }]
```

In this example, I am guessing that the data is being pulled from an external source and that the map data is the 'iso-a2' part of the array.

If this is the case, then why can't I supply this with my data....as an example see the added array with my data.....(just one example given for Denmark)

```
var mydata = [
      {
           "iso-a2": "dk",
           "value": 30
       },
]
```

and then do

```
series : [{
     data : mydata,
     mapData: Highcharts.maps['custom/world'],
     joinBy: ['iso-a2', 'value'],
     name: 'Population density',
     states: {
          hover: {
          color: '#BADA55'
          }
     }
 }]
```

This does not work.....any guidance at all (other than simply pointing me to docs would be greatly appreciated)

Answer (score 1):

The `joinBy` specifies on which value you *map* a country with your data. With

```
joinBy: ['iso-a2', 'code']
```

you say that the `'iso-a2'` value of the mapData should be equal to the `'code'` value of your data. Therefore, your data must have this format:

```
var mydata = [
      {
           "code": "dk",
           "value": 30
       },
       /* ... */
]
```